# Change voice/pitch while recording audio

Tags: android, audio

I am using the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class to record an user's voice through mic. Is there anyway to change the voice or `pitch` of the user during the recording in progress. If there is no such way, how can I modulate the output audio file and alter its `pitch` and save the file back. I don't need the solution to alter the pitch while playing the audio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would involve passing the data you get from the `AudioRecord` through some kind of filter. The easiest such filter would be one that does nearest-neighbor sampling. The second easiest would probably be linear interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about preserving playback speed, then most simple solution is to change playback speed. I.e. you can record a sound in 22050 samples per second rate, and then put it in a file, as if it was recorded in 44100 sps. When file will be played, it will be 2 times faster and, respectively, one octave higher pitch.

If you want to preserve the sampling rate, or you want to change speed in some fractional ration, then you need to apply some resampling algorithm to your sound data.

If you want to change only pitch while preserving playback time, you need to implement some algorithm on your own.
There are a lot of algorithms that allows to change a pitch. They varying on their sound quality. 
For my taste, better quality could be obtain by performing FFT-based time stretch algorithm, which will make your sound longer or shorter while preserving pitch. After that apply a resampling algorithm with reciprocal scale, which will change both pitch and speed, and speed will be returned back to original, while pitch will be changed as you want.

I don't think there are solutions in stile "someObject.doEverythingGoodForMe()" that will be work on all platforms.